Bug in Cycles when handling overlapping objects with transparency?
I tried to model a floret-alike tissue by using multiple instances of the same object (roughly a plane made into a half-sphere) distributed on top of the other object.
I used a material which is essentially a mix shader that joins transparency BSDF and emission node plus noise mask that creates a hair-alike structure on the edges of the floret object.
Everything looks ok when I have a small number of non-overlapping objects but it quickly gets messy sometimes when I increase the density. I think it depends on topology plus perhaps some other factors. Observed this effect in Blender 4.1, not sure if other versions behave differently. Also, to my surprise it doesn't always work this way and things change depending on scale of the object and its topology.
I wonder if it is a known issue? It is clearly a some sort of limitations related to the use of overlapping object that probably overwhelms the renderer.
Here is the sample render, note black spots on the edge of the center object:

Source file:


Trying to use the search here helps finding a lot of answers to this recurring question...

Sorry for posting the duplicate, I honestly did try to find it but the issues I found didn't seem to directly relate to the issue I had. After seeing an answer I did find similar questions related to hair rendering issue.

Also, to be honest, I was quite sure that I stumbled upon a bug in Blender when I saw this rendering artifact. I didn't hope that it would be so easy fix :)

You need to increase the maximum number of transparency bounces in your render settings.



Yes, that's exactly what was missing. Thank you very much!
